# Why is StreamWriter adding random bytes to a file?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to translate a virtual key code with ToAsciiEx() and write it to a debug file. For some reason, the output file contains a load of random trash bytes interspersed with the key codes I want to log.

I'm importing ToAsciiEx() like this:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern int ToAsciiEx(uint uVirtKey, uint uScanCode, byte[] lpKeyState, [Out] StringBuilder lpChar, uint uFlags, IntPtr hkl);
```

And the code:

```
byte[] state = new byte[256];
GetKeyboardState(state);
        
StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder(new String('\0', 32), 32);
int ret = ToAsciiEx((uint)vkCode, 0, state, s, 0, IntPtr.Zero);
        
string k = "";
if (ret == 1 && s.Length > 0)
{
    k = s.ToString();
}
        
var logFile = "DebugLog.txt";
var logPath = Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables("%HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%") + "\\" + logFile;
using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(logPath, true))
{
    sw.Write(k);
}
```

Passing the virtual key codes for 'Test', I get this: TSÕà[Õ-ÕØé¿eê¿sê¿tê¿

Could this be an encoding issue? Or is ToAsciiEx() not writing a null-terminator perhaps?

Thanks!

Comment: it appears that you might be requesting too much of `ToAsciiEx` - why not pass it a buffer of only 2 chars?

Comment: Do note that the [default StreamWriter encoding is UTF-8 without a BOM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamwriter.-ctor?view=net-6.0#system-io-streamwriter-ctor(system-string-system-boolean)), so while your ASCII characters will be fine to put into the file, the actual file encoding won't be ASCII if that is what you are expecting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The return value from `ToAsciiEx` [tells you how many characters were copied to the output](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-toasciiex#return-value), but you never use that information to trim the `StringBuilder`.

The Windows API has no idea what a .NET `StringBuilder` class is, and doesn't change its length.  It's writing data into a memory space that was prepared for it by the magic of p/invoke.... and then p/invoke copies the contents into the `StringBuilder`.  But `s` still has the length it was created with.

Try `k = s.ToString(0, ret);`